# Circuit reduction: Voltage across terminals

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, kirchhoffs-laws, symmetrical-components

I'm new to electrical engineering and there is debate in my class about a problem. We are asked to find the voltage across A and B after reducing the circuit. Circuit is symmetrical.
Information given: All resistors are have 1 Ohm resistance. Incoming current is 1A and outgoing current is 1A.
I have solved it like this, as shown in the figure below. But many don't agree with this. I would like to know the expert opinion in this forum.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I would like to know the expert opinion*

Yes, your solution is correct. In other words, the "crossing" resistors marked "X" carry no current and therefore the voltage across them is zero (due to the symmetry of the other resistor values) hence, they can be regarded as open-circuit or, if you want, they can be regarded as short circuits.

Comment: Thank you so very much!